# Parsing flat file with repeating section using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a flat file with data in following format:

```
1:00 PM
Name                UniqueID 
ABX 298819 12       519440AD3

12:00 AM
Name                UniqueID 
AX1 239949 01       119440AD3
```

Where each section starts with a time, followed by headers and then values. I am trying to capture each of these sections through regex, so I can get:

```
section 1:
1:00 PM
Name                UniqueID 
ABX 298819 12       519440AD3

section 2:
12:00 AM
Name                UniqueID 
AX1 239949 01       119440AD3
```

And later parse each of these sections in to java class object, which is given below:

```
public class Section {
    String timestamp;
    List<Row> rows;
}

public class Row {
    String name;
    String uniqueId;
}
```

but I am not able to extract the "text" between two positive regex matches. Below is the regular expression i tried:

```
((1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)?(?i)(am|pm))(?=.*)
```

But it returns only the time values:

```
10:30 AM
1:00 PM
1:30 PM
10:30 AM
1:00 PM
1:30 PM
```

I even tried adding `Pattern.MULTILINE` to `Pattern` but it didn't work either.

Comment: What are you trying to extract?

Comment: Try this: `(\d+):(\d+)\s(PM|AM)\s*Name\s*UniqueID\s*(\w.*?)\s(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+([\d\w]+)` You only need global enabled. What are you trying to exact btw? Try using a regex visualizer like regexr.com

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the structure you showed us repeats throughout the file, then there are four types of lines in sequence: timestamp, header, data, empty line.

For example, if you want to separate the unique ID from the name, you could try:

```
String third = "ABX 298819 12       519440AD3";
String uniqueId = third.replaceAll(".*\\s+(\\w+)", "$1");
String name = third.replaceAll("(.*)\\s+\\w+", "$1");
```

Comment: _"I think you can handle this without regular expressions."_ You are still using regexp however, just not a big one.

Comment: @LakatosGyula I meant to remove that before I posted, sorry.  My point was simply that I view parsing the text as being the workhorse here, with just a zest of regex sprinkled to make it interesting.